# Set up alarm clock in llama based on location

Tags: alarm, llama

Is there a way to set up an alarm clock based on your location using llama? I am using a HTC Desire X with Android 4.1.1.

I guess that I will need to use Alarm clock app somehow, I am just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can create a simple alarm clock with Llama.

First, you need to learn the cell tower ID of the location(s) you want to use. Llama uses cell towers instead of GPS (by default, at least) because GPS is much more battery intensive. As long as each location is more than a few miles apart, you should be fine.

Second, you set up an `event`. For each location, you set up two events, one for entering and one for leaving. I suggest simply setting a Llama variable when you enter, for example a variable called `Location` gets set to the name of the area when you enter, and gets cleared when you leave.

Next, set up your alarm events. You create an event, and have two `conditions`. The first one will check that variable to see if we are in the right place. The second condition will be based on the time, called `Time Between`. Set the time-frame to be one minute. If you also want to care about the Day of Week, you can do that as a third condition.

If both (or all three) conditions are met, then the `action` will be run. Add an action to `Play a Sound`, `Speak`, `Vibrate`, or do whatever you want for your actual alarm.

Once you have your first alarm event created, you can long-press on it to copy it and make as many alarms as you want.